# Django Session Variable Is Accessible Even After Deletion

Tags: python, django

I tried to delete the session after the work is complete. But, it still shows a different value when checking if the session variable exists.

```
if 'order_id' in request.session:
    # here the value of session variable is 28
    del request.session['order_id']
    request.session.modified = True
```

When I checked again it returned True even though I deleted the variable,

```
if 'order_id' in request.session:
    # here the value of session variable is 5118
    print('yes')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `request.session['order_id']` is created for the second time from your another view function after you delete it. That is why you are seeing a different value.

Check all your views.py file where you assigned a value to `request.session['order_id']` unknowingly.